# Is the charge static or not and which field does it apply to in the Lorentz force?

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, charge, inertial-frames

Is it on a static charge on a magno-ecletric field?  or on a moving charge on an electric field only or magnetic field only?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen 2 definitions of the Lorentz Force:

1. $\mathbf{F} = q\,\mathbf{v}\times\mathbf{B}\qquad$ (a.k.a, magnetic force)
2. $\mathbf{F} = q \left(\mathbf{E} + \mathbf{v}\times\mathbf{B}\right)$

The more common, the one I use and the one you seem to be refering to is the second one. Therefore, the force aplies both to moving and static charges. To static charges it only remains the electrostatic force $\mathbf{F}_{E} = q \mathbf{E}$.